# How to store UIView and all its subviews and its properties and all Gesture recognizer as it is

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am creating dynamically some "n" number of `UIView` Object in my application.I can able to drag, drop these objects to any position in the screen & change their some of property.

1. one subview contain `imageview`, other subview contain `textview`,
2. one subview with `tap Gesture`, other subview have pan gesture and
3. one subview is the instance of my customized drawing view(`ACEDRawingView`).

want to save all these details with persistance storage ,so that whenever i launched the application next time, i can able to see those already created object.

I'm a relatively new iOS developer, with most of my previous experience coming from .NET. My application is a canvas like system in that there is a parent `UIView` that contains all the objects the user is placing/resizing/etc as subviews. I want to be able to save these positions/configurations to named files.

Originally I thought I could do this using `NSCoding`, but this doesn't seem to be a good solution for multiple file saving.

So I looked at `Core Data`, but I'm not sure how I can create Core Data objects of existing Cocoa `UIKit` classes like `UIView`.

Comment: You should be able to use NSCoding to serialize your uiviews, as UIView implements the NSCoding protocol.  What problems are you having with multiple file saving?  With Core Data you could create an entity with data attributes to save your serialized UIView data, but this would still require you to use NSCoding protocol.

Comment: @Arun Raj have you found any solution for this?